# Highlight a cell in JTable with an Icon in it

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtable, jlabel

I have a JTable with 3 columns in it. 1. Icon, 2. Name of file or folder, 3. File type or "Folder". I draw the Icon using a JLabel (I set background + png image) within the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method. Initially I draw an alternating background of the JLable either "white" or "grey" since those are the colors that the `JTable` Swing component alternates to draw the table. Now, when I select a row, the Icon (the first column) background does not get redrawn to "dark blue" same as the rest of the row. [image: Illustrative Screenshot]

**Here are my questions:**

**General**
1) How can also highlight the Icon cell when highlighting a row (pointers will suffice, no code expected)?

**Specific**

1.1) Do I have to use JLabel? Why can't I just e.g. `.SetValueAt("image.png",0,0)`

1.2) I tried the `getColumnClass(...)` but that seems to redraw ALL cells in a given column. Is that expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) The `javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer` gets an `isSelected` parameter when it is called. You can easily write your own `TableCellRenderer` by inheriting from `JLabel` (for example) and overridding `getTableCellRendererComponent`: Adjust the Object and return `this`. Having your own renderer also allows you to set a breakpoint and really understand what is happening.

1.1 + 1.2.) Both `setValueAt` and `getColumnClass` are part if the model and will probably not solve your problem with the selected background.

You do not have to use `JLabel`: If you look at the return type from `getTableCellRendererComponent` you notice it is `Component` (not even `JComponent`). I guess `JLabel` is just customary because it normally has all the features you want for the renderer and the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` also uses `JLabel`. For the most freedom I advise you to use `JComponent` and write your own `paintComponent`, but in this case you probably don't have to do that.

Comment: Tilo, thanks. Got it. Works. One last thing before I accept this as an anwer. Do I have to use JLabel? Is there a way, not to use any `Component`, just an Image?

Answer (score 3):

assuming the striping (alternate white/grey background) happens automatically in your LAF (Nimbus?), you shouldn't need a custom renderer: the table already has a default renderer registered for Icon and ImageIcon class. Make sure your tableModel returns one of those classes as columnClass for the first column and enjoy the automatics :-)

Here's a quick code snippet:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 2) {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            return Icon.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

};
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles();
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
for (File f : files) {
    model.addRow(new Object[] {fsv.getSystemIcon(f), fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f)});
}
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: Thanks Kleopatra. You're right, Nimbus it is. I may have to read up more on columnClass. So far I thought it would paint one icon only.